# Bitmaps and out of memory error

Tags: android

I am trying to save many bitmaps in my app's folder on sdcard. However I am getting out of memory error. What is the best way to handle bitmaps and memory in this situation. Also where will I call bitmap.recycle() looking at below code? Thanks

Here is the code with which I am saving bitmaps on sdcard

```
Bitmap b1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sky);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bStream1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    b1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bStream1);


    File file= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "AppName" + "/image1.png");
    if(!file.exists()) {
        try {

            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(bStream1.toByteArray());
            fos.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this happening while above code has been run in a separate AsyncTask (i.e. in a separate thread)? Or are you trying to do this on a UI thread? Usually such operations should be done in a separate thread.

Comment: when the app loads , that's when I am trying to store images on sdcard

Comment: Well that is pretty wrong code using Bitmap and BitmapFactory causing your problems. Why dont you just copy the files? Open an InputStream from the resource and copy in a loop to the FileOutputStream.  `file.createNewFile();`. Remove that statement.

Comment: What size are the bitmaps you are loading?

Comment: 160 x 160 for width and height, size is 20kb for each image

Comment: File size doesn't mean anything.  Each image needs about 75kb on the heap.  How many are you loading?

Comment: I am loading 40 images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think to use `bitmap.recycle()` and keep your code nice, you should move `if(!file.exists())` into `try` statement, and then in `finally` recycle your Bitmap

```
try {
    if(!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(bStream1.toByteArray());
            fos.close();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    b1.recycle()
}
```

Something like this.

Comment: I also used BitmapFactory options.inSampleSize